# react-navigation change active tab from nested navigator

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am looking at `react-navigation` and am having a lot of trouble pushing a new screen to a tab other than the one the user is currently on and having it switch tabs and push the route I specify.

The navigation structure I'm using is as follows with a StackNavigator with a screen of a TabNavigator and each of the tabs have screens of StackNavigators.

```
StackNavigator({
  root: {
    screen: TabNavigator({
      shopTab: {
        screen: StackNavigator({
          shopIndex: ShopIndexScreen,
          product: ProductScreen
        })
      },
      listsTab: {
        screen: StackNavigator({
          listsIndex: ListsIndexScreen
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Let's say I want to push a product screen from the `listsTab`. I want to have it switch tabs and push the product route onto the StackNavigator on the `shopTab`. I have not been able to find a way to do this.

I was hoping that I would be able to use `this.props.navigation.navigate('product')` in the `ListsIndexScreen` but it seems that with the navigators being nested like this the library is unable to find the screen with the `product` key.

I've also tried to use a combination of `this.props.navigation.dispatch` and `NavigationActions.navigate/replace` but none of those worked either.

I assume I'm missing something simple as this seems like pretty basic behavior to be able to write into an app, but I'm unable to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, stack in tab in stack, all connected and navigating via navigate.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const device_width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const device_height = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);

const viewStyle = {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    width:device_width, 
    height: device_height, 
};

const Home = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'green'}}>
        <Text>HOME</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home2 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
        <Text>HOME2</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home3 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'yellow'}}>
        <Text>HOME3</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home4 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
        <Text>HOME4</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home5 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'teal'}}>
        <Text>HOME5</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home6 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        <Text>HOME6</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home7 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'lightgrey'}}>
        <Text>HOME7</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)

const Home8 = ({ navigation }) => (
    <View style={{...viewStyle, backgroundColor:'lightgreen'}}>
        <Text>HOME8</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}><Text>GO TO HOME</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home2')}><Text>GO TO HOME2</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home3')}><Text>GO TO HOME3</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home4')}><Text>GO TO HOME4</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home5')}><Text>GO TO HOME5</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home6')}><Text>GO TO HOME6</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home7')}><Text>GO TO HOME7</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home8')}><Text>GO TO HOME8</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)



const StackNav2 = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home6: {
            screen: Home6,
        },
        Home7: {
            screen: Home7,
        },
        Home8: {
            screen: Home8,
        }
    },
    {
   headerMode: 'none',
   mode: 'card',
   navigationOptions: {
     gesturesEnabled: true,
   },
   initialRouteName: 'Home7',
}
);

const TabNav = TabNavigator(
    {
        Home4: {
            screen: Home4,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Home4',
            },
        },
        Home5: {
            screen: Home5,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Home5',
            },
        },
        StackNav2: {
            screen: StackNav2,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Home6',
            },
        },
    }, {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        animationEnabled: false,
        lazy: true,
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'white',
            activeBackgroundColor: 'rgba(152, 187, 45, 1)',
        },
});

const Nav = StackNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Home,
        },
        Home2: {
            screen: Home2,
        },
        Home3: {
            screen: Home3,
        },
        Tab: {
            screen: TabNav,
        }
    },
    {
   headerMode: 'none',
   mode: 'card',
   navigationOptions: {
     gesturesEnabled: true,
   },
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
}
);




export default Nav;
```